# Notification is not receiving iOS

Tags: ios, swift, onesignal

In my `iOS` app I am using `onesignal SDK` for push notification integration. I have completed all the steps mentioned in  one signal documentation and there is no problem in receiving notification from `onesignal` dashboard. But it is not receiving notification from `back end`. In android no problem in receiving notification.

I am using `Xcode 10 and iOS 12.1`.

What will be the issue?

Comment: Check whether backend has device token or not. Also check on push try online with device token, whether it's working or not.

Answer (score 0):

if android push is fine, Check push certificate file and token, You can check using apns app.

"apns" search and any free app download. Do it test.

You have to prepare push certificate and token.